# Screenshot with "select the area to grab" option - how to "unselect" grabbed area?

Tags: screenshot

I'm trying to save as a picture a screenshot with "select the area to grab" option. But the selected area is marked with different color - as selected area - which is visible on the resulting image. How to make it in normal color?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, with `gnome-flashback`. For making screenshot I'm using the screenshot tool (it's in *Accessories*). I was trying (according to first comment) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScr</kbd>, but the result is the same.

It looks like this:

[image: grabbed screenshot area]

Comment: shift-PrtScr enables the select area option in Unity, which once selected should give you the choice of copying to clipboard or saving to storage. I tired both of these options and neither retains the coloured box used to indicated the original selection. Could you give more details? I'm on LTS 16.04.1

Comment: Could you try `gnome-screenshot -a` from the terminal? Obviously, you'll need to keep the area you want to grab uncovered by the terminal.

Comment: Still the same...

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you are seeing?

Comment: @Ron In the body of the question I've added a screenshot of my question...

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Unity.

Comment: in terminal use `ll ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` and ensure file is owned by your user ID.

Comment: @maria, Could you add the output of `xprop -id $(xprop -root -notype | awk '$1=="_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK:"{print $5}') -notype -f _NET_WM_NAME 8t` . It could be, window manage is not composite.

Comment: I don't think this behaviour is intended. Maybe a bug report would be warranted?

Comment: Yes, definitelly report a bug because this is not normal behavior, and in the mean time use something else. For instace Shutter or any other screenshot tool.

Comment: @DavidFoerster How should I report a bug?

Comment: To report a bug see [How do I report a bug?](/q/5121/175814). You can report it on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot) (after checking for duplicates). At a quick glance I found two similar bug reports: [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1089069), [2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1406538).

Comment: I tested Gnome (compiz) and I have a blue overlay in my screenshots. I found [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/771875) bug. Sometimes it may have relation with yours too.  I have this problem with compiz only.